# Embed YouTube video with access token

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I need to embed a private video in a Web App.

I already generated an access token to see the video through a direct URL (like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video_id>&access_token=<access_token>`) and tested it.

Now I need to embed that video into an `iframe` tag inside the page, but it looks like the URL used for embedding it (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/<video_id>?access_token=<access_token>`) does not support the access token.

I've tried to access my web page with after logging in with the owner of the video and I can see my video, so it's not an error in the embed URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution to be able to play embedded videos using access token?